# How to update Time in DOM In Vue.js without uisng set-timeout or set-interval

Tags: vue.js

I want to update time without using setInterval function in Vue. Is there any way? It's work with setInterval like the code below. However, I want something inbuilt in vue or any other best/different way to do it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  seconds: '',
  },
  mounted:function(){
    setInterval( () => {         
      this.seconds= new Date().getSeconds();
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
   
<div id="app">
  Realtime Second = {{seconds}}           
</div>
```

Comment: There's no built-in vue functionality for that. Using `setInterval` is probably the best way. There are probably other javascript libraries that trigger events at intervals in a more abstracted way. But the "best way to do it" is open to debate and too broad of a question.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I will look for other Javascript libraries. Just Curious about this time update.

Comment: Why? `setInterval` is the correct tool to do what you want. It is built into JavaScript. What is the problem you are trying to solve by avoiding it?

Answer (score 0):

For things that need to change after a single update cycle we have `this.$nextTick`. This is, however, not really useful for a timer. That makes `window.setInterval` the next best thing.

Keep in mind that just like with manually added event handlers, timeouts and intervals must be manually cleared in a lifecycle hook. Your current code should be something like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seconds: (new Date).getSeconds(),

    intervalRef: null
  },
  mounted () {
    this.intervalRef = window.setInterval(() => {
      this.seconds = (new Date).getSeconds();
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    if (this.intervalRef) {
      window.clearInterval(this.intervalRef);
      this.intervalRef = null;
    }
  }
});
```